# riak startup issue

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, riak

I am trying to setup riak 3 node cluster using their very basic 45 minute tutorial, however my first node always fail to start with following error inside erlang.log.1:

```
=====
===== LOGGING STARTED Tue Jan 10 12:13:08 EST 2012
=====
Exec: /root/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/dev/dev1/erts-5.8.4/bin/erlexec -boot /root/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/dev/dev1/releases/1.0.2/riak             -embedded -config /root/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/dev/dev1/etc/app.config             -args_file /root/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/dev/dev1/etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /root/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/dev/dev1
Erlang R14B03 (erts-5.8.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]


Crash dump was written to: log/erl_crash.dump
The code server called the unloaded module `erlang'
```

Here is the link i am following for my setup:
http://wiki.basho.com/Building-a-Development-Environment.html

I even tried `make rel` option but with same error.

```
# uname -a
Linux li110-56 3.0.4-x86_64-linode21 #1 SMP Thu Sep 1 21:28:01 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Log directory doesn't contain any error.log :

```
root@li110-56:~/packages/basho-riak-782cc74/rel/riak# ls -l log/
total 648
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    645 2012-01-10 12:21 erlang.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root root 651183 2012-01-10 12:22 erl_crash.dump
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    292 2012-01-10 12:21 run_erl.log
```

Note: Got it working, probably was an error because of duplicates left while downgrading from R14B04 to R14B03. I retried by completely removing /usr/lib/erlang and it worked as expected.

Comment: How did you install erlang and what linux distro are you on? The problem is something screwy with the erlang installation as it's not able to find/load its core module. Can you start up the erlang shell with `erl` ?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 11.04, system wide "erl" and "erts-VSN/bin/erl" both works equally for me `Erlang R14B03 (erts-5.8.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1> `

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you have questions about Riak, feel free to contact us on the mailing list - http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com or on #riak on IRC

Comment: thanks brian, i m using riak extensively in my xmpp based applications. I have just switched to riak and enjoying it. I will surely catch up with riak mailing list and irc channels.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, make sure that the version of Erlang installed on your system is compatible with the version of Riak you installed. Riak isn't using the latest and greatest Erlang build and it will cause problems.

Comment: As per riak wiki, i get an impression that I need to have R14B0[2,3] to build riak. I initially had R14B04 which i have already downgraded to R14B03 for riak only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe first of all you need to look  at erl_crash.dump

You can find the cause of crashing - its string that starts with "Slogan:" in the erl_crash.dump

Comment: I have riak-1.0.2.zip which i downloaded from github tag list. Further initially i had R14B04 which i already downgraded to R14B03 for riak, however i get an erl_crash.dump with starting few lines as `=erl_crash_dump:0.1
Tue Jan 10 12:13:10 2012
Slogan: The code server called the unloaded module \`erlang'
System version: Erlang R14B03 (erts-5.8.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]
Compiled: Tue Jan 10 08:54:17 2012
Taints:
Atoms: 10298`